# wpf Transfer Controls from one window to the other

Tags: c#, wpf

Transfer Controls from one window to the other.The original window use .How to transfer the controls in the  to the other?Thanks.

Comment: Transfer controls?  What?  Copy the XAML of one window to the other?

Comment: Yes,move the controls in the window to the other.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: show the contents of the window in other window of another computor

Comment: Oh my god! You really asking to move a control from the window on one computer to a window aof a program running on a different computer???? That is completely nonsense!

Comment: using socket and I need to get all the controls of the window.

Comment: @user998703 What you want to do is probably not to move the actual controls between windows/applications/computers but transfer the data used to render the controls. Transmitting data between computers "using a socket" is not really something you accomplish with WPF.

Comment: @Oskar Yes,but I dont know how to get the data with wpf.

Comment: A web based solution sounds more probable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing u can do is

- XAML Serialization http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/82990/XAML-Serialization of your WPF Controls (or XAML Object), then
- Use Windows Messaging http://boycook.wordpress.com/2008/07/29/c-win32-messaging-with-sendmessage-and-wm_copydata/ to send and retrieve Serialized XAML between two (or more) apps and re-create your Control (or XAML Object).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup some sort of connection between the two client applications and serialize the objects over the network connection (slow) or send the minimum information required to manually reconstruct the controls properly on the other side.